# request failed with status code 403(forbidden) in axios.get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i am building a simple lyrics finder app using react.js and using musixmatch api. when i request the api i get this error in console`Error: Request failed with status code 403 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle (settle.js:17) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)`

this is my componentDidMount() function

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Context = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends Component {
    state = {
        track_list: [],
        heading: "Top 10 Tracks"
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(
            `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=it&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=${
                process.env.REACT_APP_MM_KEY}`
        )
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={this.state} >
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

Comment: are u sure ~https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=it&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=~ url correct ?

Comment: when i enter the url in browser with api key then it works. I also tried enetring the api key directly ( without cors-anywhere) but i still get error.

Comment: I believe that cors-anywhere server is limiting access, you're going to have to run your own in that case.

Answer (score 5):

status code 403 means that you are not authorized. You could either have entered a wrong api key or maybe your process.env does not work (try to enter the api key directly!).

And are u sure that you need cors-anywhere? Did you try without?

EDIT:

you can test if your api key works when you simply enter the url with your key into the browser (without cars-anywhere) like so:

https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=it&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=your_api_key

EDIT 2:

this works, when I try it inside a React application: So the problem must be at your process.env implementation.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=it&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=your_api_key`
    )
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: yes api is working fine when i enter the url in the browser(without cors-anywhere) . Now what should i do. Please help me I am begnner in react and javascript.

Comment: try to use the url inside of your component without cors-anywhere and with the api key directly (paste the code that worked in the url into your get request).

Comment: i did exactly what you said but now i am getting these errors.....                                                                GET https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=us&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=e3a6024b03658f80e2ced2b90700028d net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: and also these:                                                                    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=us&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=e3a6024b03658f80e2ced2b90700028d' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
context.js:13 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Comment: see my edited answer above. It works (even with cors-anywhere) on my side. Check your  env implementation!

Comment: i tried a different api key. Again the url works in browser and same url gives this error in console:  Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Comment: the issue is finally solved now. after  opening the link in browser with cors-anywhere i had to click on the button(Request Temporary access to demo server) and after i clicked on that button and refreshed the react-app i got the desired result.

Comment: I did the same mistake. I have entered wrong credentials. Your answer helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it was problem with axios version. so if you tried all solutions and still can not find the root cause, you can try to change axios version. I was using was assume role credentials to make a request against a service and always getting rejected with 403 even though the credentials were correct. I was using axios 1.3.1 but then I downgraded it to 0.27.2 and now my code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

**add in your Header**

```
  const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

    headers.append('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
```

**Add in your Header if you facing 403 Error**

**headers.append('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');**

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using an API key, you might have exhausted your request. You only get about 50 request thereabout per hour or something like, except you use an API key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).